# Multiply 2 very large data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I have 2 dataframes in R as below

Data Frame 1

```
structure(list(X1 = c(1, 4, 3), X2 = c(2, 1, 2), X3 = c(3, 1, 
1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Data Frame 2

```
structure(list(X1 = c(0.5, 0.1), X2 = c(0.7, 0.2), X3 = c(0.3, 
0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I want to multiply each row of DF1 with every row of DF2 and perform some calculation as below. This is a sort of matrix multiplication along with additional calculations

1. After matrix multiplication, I will calculate `1/(1+exp(-x))` for every cell in resultant matrix
2. and lastly, take the column sum of the matrix

The above dataset is just a dummy set. In actual, DF1 has 1.1 million rows while DF2 has 65000 rows.
While doing matrix multiplication, I get error

```
cannot allocate vector of Size 560 GB
```

Is there any alternative to this. Also, I am looking for time effective solution due to large data frames.
May be Data table ?

Thanks,

Comment: How many columns are there? If your data have 560GB, you might not be able to fit them into the memory at all. What are the data types - in your example I see ints and floats. Is there any way to make them all integer and if possible, limit their sizes? (this might help a little, but not that much)

Comment: DF1 has 1.1 million rows and 16 columns
DF2 has 65000 rows and 16 columns

The data type is float

Comment: Since you are doing arithmetic rather than a matrix multiplication, it seems you could do the calculations piecewise. I.e., by smaller subsets of rows.  And just aggregate the final results at the end.

Comment: Dear oh dear. If DF1 and DF2 both only had 1 column and you wanted to take all combinations of their rows, the resulting DF would have 16K * 1,1M = ~ 17G rows. 4bytes per row(32 bit integer) and we are at 68GB memory. Now take that times 16 and we are at ~1088GB of memory. By which point I am somewhat surprised that the allocated vector was only half size. And by this moment we are kind of running not only out of memory but out of disk space. Please correct me if my napkin-math was off somewhere ^^.

Comment: I understand the challenge. Is there any other alternative solution to this ?

Comment: Why do you need to take all the combinations? What is the use case? Would it be possible to filter out the data to a reasonable size? It is hard to guess at the alternatives while only knowing what you want to compute and not why. Not saying that I have a magical solution to solve all your issues.

Comment: Also expanding on @SteveM, you can perform even the matrix multiplication piecewise. The formulae are for example [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/rvdg/LinAlgBook/Section2-5.pdf). This would help IF you can fit your data to your hard drive and IF you can expect the computation to finish within reasonable amount of time. It might require a cluster or something similar though as you need to compute each of the 272GB cells and then pass them through your exponential function. It is still within the realm of possibility though. Just somewhat out of a reasonable reach for a personal computer.

Comment: Tried piecewise matrix multiplication but it is getting time consuming process.